# Can't public static on a final

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I am sure there's a super simple explanation and it'll make me feel stupid, but I just can't figure it out.
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3UHJz3SP) , line 18:

```
public static boolean loadTextures() {
    try {
        final Texture STONE = loadPNG("main\\textures\\stone.png"); // This line here I can't do public static final...         
    } catch (IOException e) {
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I would like `STONE` to be `public static final`, but eclipse says only `final` is a legal modifier.
How would I go about declaring a `public static final` variable?

Comment: `public` and `static` are modifiers for fields. They don't apply to local variables.

Comment: Some vote happy peeps up in this bad boy

Comment: Alright, I got it, thanks guys now I can continue with my game xD I never knew you couldn't public or static on local variables because I never tried before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't declare a static variable inside a method, since a method has only local variables.

Move it outside your method.

Change this :

```
public static boolean loadTextures() {
                try {
                        final Texture STONE = loadPNG("main\\textures\\stone.png"); // This line here I can't do public static
```

to this :

```
public static final Texture STONE = loadPNG("main\\textures\\stone.png");
public static boolean loadTextures() {
                try {
```

Comment: I don't like, that you move the `loadPNG` method call outside the try/catch block. But I guess, this is the only to keep it `final`.

Answer (score 1):

`public` and `static` are modifiers that can be applied to **data members**. In your example, `STONE` is a local variable in the scope of the `loadTextures()` method.

You could define it as a `public static final` data member, and initialize in a `static` block:

```
public static final Texture STONE;
static {
    try {
        STONE = loadPNG("main\\textures\\stone.png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // some error handling...
    }
 }
```

The biggest problem here, as can be seen is the exception handling. Since this is invoked when the class is loaded by the classloader, there's no real **good** way to handle potential exceptions there.

Answer (score 0):

`final` is the only valid modifier allowed for a local variable. You need to move it outside the method and declare the variable at class level.